# HTTP Post Error 400 using RestSharp and HTTPClient - How to Diagnose?

Tags: c#, post, .net-core, httpclient, restsharp

I'm porting a java application to C#. There is an HTTP post request with some key value pairs. No authentication required. I've also been provided a working python example that POSTs in a similar way. The endpoint is good.

I've tried both HTTPClient and RestSharp with similar results.

I wonder if I'm doing this wrong, I'm doing something like this:

```
var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    { "A", a },
                    { "B", b },
                    { "C", c },
                    { "D", d }
                }
var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
Uri u = new Uri(myURI);
var response = await client.PostAsync(u,content);
var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

The python looks very similar to this:

```
>>> payload = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}

>>> r = requests.post("https://httpbin.org/post", data=payload)
>>> print(r.text)
```

The java and python examples, look very similar, building a list of parameters and posting. The rest sharp looks similar, but also fails with the same error. I'm looking for some things to try, that I don't know. Is is a header or content type change? Different way to submit the data? I'm lost here.

Comment: The is no real reason to use RestSharp in this day and age, use IHttpClientFactory. Also, if you are trying to debug the difference between be calls, use Fiddler

Comment: Are you certain that the endpoint accepts `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content? Is that how the Java/python examples are posting the data?

Comment: @devNull I'm not certain. I was thought to change that, but wasn't sure I was doing it correctly. The Python code uses `requests` library and there are no header/content changes in the code; Seemingly default post request.

Comment: @TheGeneral I will try fiddler. Thx

Comment: Fiddler nicely formatted the error.. It was an invalid input for a parameter. Fixed and it works.  btw, python requests posted the same way at postasync.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the comments in the question, Fiddler was suggested to diagnose the issue.

Fiddler nicely formatted the response text which showed an invalid parameter. Parameter corrected and everything is working.